# Circle in CSS not following mouse movement using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to HTML, CSS and JS, I created a circle and a dot inside the circle in CSS and I wanted the circle and the dot to follow my mouse movement while browsing my website. I have looked everywhere, but being a newbie I am not expert enough to solve this problem.
If anyone can point out what I am doing wrong, I'd really appreciate that. Thank you!

```js
const mouseCircle = document.querySelector(".mouse-circle");
const mouseDot = document.querySelector(".mouse-dot");

//Mouse Circle

const mouseCircleFn = (x,y) => {
    mouseCircle.style.cssText = 'top: ${y}px; left: ${x}px';
    mouseDot.style.cssText = 'top:${y}px; left: ${x}px';
};

document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    let x = e.clientX;
    let y = e.clientY;

    mouseCircleFn(x,y);

});

//End of Mouse Circle
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?        family=Jura:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jura:wght@300;400;500;600;700&family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');


/* Common Styles */

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'Jura', sans-serif ;

}

html{
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

/* End of Common Styles */

/* Mouse Circle */

.mouse-circle,
.mouse-dot{
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 300;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.mouse-circle{
    width: 6rem;   
    height: 6rem;
    border: 0.1rem solid #c7a622;

}

.mouse-dot{
    width: .5rem;
    height: .5rem;
    background-color: #9b0e0e;
}

/* End of mouse circle */

/* Page BG */
.page-bg{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.7), rgba(0,0,0,.7)), url(images/bg.jpg) center no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
/* End of Page BG*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Zareef Hossain - Designer/Programmer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Mouse Circle -->

    <div class="mouse-circle"></div>
    <div class="mouse-dot"></div>
    <!-- End of mouse circle -->

    <!-- Page Container-->

    <div class="container"></div>
    <!-- page BG -->
    <div class="page-bg"></div>
    <!-- End page BG -->

    <!-- End of page container-->

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just took a look at your code and updated my answer. You can still use your original method if you like, there was just a small error with your syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're just using the wrong type of quotes in this case, make sure to use backticks when using the `${}` variable syntax.

```js
const mouseCircleFn = (x,y) => {
    mouseCircle.style.cssText = `top: ${y}px; left: ${x}px`;
    mouseDot.style.cssText = `top:${y}px; left: ${x}px`;
};
```

However, a better solution might be to use the css [cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) property and use your own custom image or svg.

```css
body {
  cursor: url(image.png), pointer;
}
```

Check out [this post](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-cursors/) if you're interested in learning more about cursor manipulation in css.

Comment: Thank you so much!! 
I really appreciate your help.